# Job search: discreetly searching for roles, whilst in a role

Tags: job-search, linkedin

I'm currently in a role where I am happy but I'll be moving to a new city soon depending on a few personal factors. I have been looking for jobs on LinkedIn, StackOverflow and other websites.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to have access to a larger range of recruiters/jobs without announcing it publicly (I have my employer on LinkedIn), I've directly approached recruiters but I still feel they don't always have a role I would have preference to (i.e. a junior role or location of said role).

Normally I would make a public announcement on LinkedIn and the recruiters would normally approach me depending on the criteria (thus more opportunities to find the right role), I'm avoiding doing this for:

- The move may not 100% happen (so I would love to stay here, if it doesn't)
- It's way before the time-frame where I have to hand my notice in, so I don't want them to think I'm unhappy here/being disrespectful in anyway.
- General courtesy to my current employer/colleagues.

Is there anything I could do to find a larger array of opportunities, *discreetly*?

Comment: I feel like looking for another job when you may not move after all is playing with fire a little bit. What happens if you go through a good portion of the hiring process and then discover you're not moving after all? Then you've made another company irritated with you.

Comment: Skip linkedin for now, focus on contacting local recruiters in your destination town via their websites. Get your CV to them, let them know when you're going to move, get teh interviews lined up for the week after you arrive.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense If I'm happy to apply for the role and go through the hiring process, I've indicated my intent to forgo that process and I'll move for that job. Currently I'm just looking for roles in the areas I'm potentially moving to, not applying as of yet.

Comment: @JohnHC Thanks for the tip, I'll have a gander for local recruiters now.

Comment: In my experience searching for jobs in a different city than where I live, it's very difficult to get responses from companies anyway.  Maybe recruiters can get around this somewhat.  In my case, I re-applied once I had a local address and was immediately getting much better reactions.  Instead of shopping ahead, you may want to consider saving up enough money that you can survive a couple months unemployed in the new city, and begin your search once you're there (or shortly before you move, but once it's certain at least.)

Comment: You can set your LinkedIn privacy options so that changes to your profile and new contacts aren't broadcast to people you're already connected with.

Comment: And hopefully you are NOT Bradley Wilson, Bradley Wilson :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fully understand your feelings. When I was a junior, fresh out of college, I felt like I was betraying my employer when I put feelers out for new jobs. I felt I was indebted to them.

I'm now in charge of all the developers and employees of the company, and I've faced this many times with my developers, and also with myself if I look outside for a job.

I'll tell you honestly that we don't see what you're doing. When my guys put out their resume on Monster, Indeed, Ranstaad, or hooked up with recruiters, we never saw it. **Unless** our own recruiters saw someone on job sites with a brand new updated resume, and even then they don't bother to talk to us about it because everyone has resumes on those sites.

Moving to another city is exciting and a bit scary when it comes to ensuring you have a job when you arrive. For sure you want to get your name out there, and apply for work. I would definitely work with a recruiter if I were you.  Recruiters are used to this and won't do anything to upset your current job - they have a reputation too.

I also wouldn't tell your boss at this time, until it's a for sure thing.  But yea, go ahead.

Any good boss will be glad to see you succeed in life and to excel. It's only the Sh... crappy ones that won't like it - and you don't want to work for them.

tl;dr;

1. Get in with more than 1 recruiter in the new town. You're not betraying them if you use more than one.  Recruiters sometimes have unique job opportunities others will never have.
2. Update your resume. Make sure it stands out, and is factual. we like facts more than feelings.
3. Don't put your life on hold. You said this isn't a for sure thing, so keep working hard at your current job. Have integrity and proper ethic. It will pay off 10-fold during this process. People who have 1 foot out the door are usually labeled as lazy. Don't do this. Let your boss be proud of you during this time - so in the case you are moving, he'll remember how hard you worked at the end.
4. Put your resume on job seeking sites (monster, indeed, randstad, etc.) and you'll get calls.

best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice, I will certainly be using it. It's a sticky situation because I love what I currently do and they have done a lot for me, just want to make sure everything with them is smooth as silk whatever happens.

Comment: Great advice, start looking but try and be discrete about it.